# How to compute expansion factors for hyperbolic rational maps?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry, complex-dynamics

It is a commonly-referenced result about certain rational maps acting on $\mathbb{\hat{C}}$ that they are *expanding* on a neighborhood of their Julia sets. A sufficient condition to be expanding is that all of the rational map's critical points be periodic. (See, e.g., [Chapter 19](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DsthOelUMlkC&pg=PA205&dq=%22hyperbolic%20map%22%20%22julia%20set%22%20milnor&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjz_razIfgAhWTUhUIHRNDCBEQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=%22hyperbolic%20map%22%20%22julia%20set%22%20milnor&f=false) of Milnor's "Dynamics in one complex variable".)

Take as a specific example the [Douady rabbit polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douady_rabbit), $f(z) \approx z^2 -0.12+.074i$.

*Expanding* here means that there is a constant $k>1$ so that distances grow by at least a factor of $k$ under the map on a neighborhood of its Julia set in the associated Riemannian metric.

**My question is: how can one compute a (relatively sharp) expanding constant $k$ for a given rational map?** Say, concretely, for the rabbit polynomial? An answer or a relevant reference would be greatly appreciated!

Note: finding the expanding constant should have something to do with finding a lower bound on the derivative of the map in the neighborhood of the Julia set (*edit*: in the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{C}$). But the expanding constant can't literally be this lower bound, because it may not be bigger than 1. There should be some kind of uniformization to a hyperbolic metric happening, and some kind of effective Schwarz–Ahlfors–Pick theorem, but I'm not at all sure how to even begin such a calculation.

Comment: Why do you say "it can't literally be that"? Sure, it's quite possible that a poorly chosen neighborhood will yield a lower bound that is $\le 1$. However, some better chosen neighborhood will yield a better lower bound, and as the neighborhood gets closer and closer to the Julia set $J$ itself, the lower bound on the neighborhood will approach $\min_{x \in J} |f'(x)|$.

Comment: This reference might be helpful: 

MR2109468 (2005g:37084) 
Hruska, Suzanne Lynch 
Constructing an expanding metric for dynamical systems in one complex variable. (English summary) In particular, in Section 6 the author introduces and computes a "box-expanding" constant.
Nonlinearity 18 (2005), no. 1, 81–100

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for your comment. I may be missing something, but there are examples (including the rabbit) where there are points in the Julia set where $|f'(x)|<1$---when using the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{C}$. That was the metric I meant to be referring to in my note. (I've edited to reflect this). If we instead take the "correct" metric in which the map is expanding, yes, your comment is I believe just the right thing.